# CSS last child is not working as first child is

Tags: css

for some reason i can not get last child selector working

fiddle is here - https://jsfiddle.net/1aawd1vL/7/

first child is coloring the bg red , but last child is not working , any ideas ?

```
.moohighlight:first-child td {background:red;}

.moohighlight:last-child td {background:green;}
```

also tried last-of-type

```
tr.moohighlight:first-of-type td {background:red;}

tr.moohighlight:last-of-type td  {background:green;}
```

Comment: [*The `:last-child` CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the last child element of its parent.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) This means it's not looking at the class, but at the parent's container, *then* finding the last child element, then checking if it's got the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The :last-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the last child element of its parent.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) This means it's not looking at the class, but at the parent's container, then finding the last child element, then checking if it's got the class.

You could instead use another `tbody` specifically for your `.moohighlight` element group and then you can use `:first-child` *and* `:last-child`, since it's the parent and not the subject of the selector:

```
tbody.moohighlight tr:first-child td {
    background:red;
}
tbody.moohighlight tr:last-child td {
    background:green;
}

<div class="draft_picks_container" id="draft_picks_container">
    <table class="report nocaption commishview" align="center" cellspacing="1">
        <tbody class='moohighlight'>
            <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" classname="moohighlight" class="moohighlight" id="pick_01_01">
                <td class="pick">1.01</td>
                <td class="franchise fname0006">Chocolate Thunder</td>
                <td class="selection">Bell, Le'Veon PIT RB</td>
                <td class="timestamp">3:13:14 p.m.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-position: 0px 0px; color: rgb(38, 62, 104);" classname="moohighlight" class="moohighlight" id="pick_01_02">
                <td class="pick">1.02</td>
                <td class="franchise fname0003">VACANT TEAM - 2nd pick</td>
                <td class="selection">Jeffery, Alshon CHI WR</td>
                <td class="timestamp">3:13:15 p.m.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-position: 0px 0px; color: rgb(38, 62, 104);" classname="moohighlight" class="moohighlight" id="pick_01_02">
                <td class="pick">1.02</td>
                <td class="franchise fname0003">VACANT TEAM - 2nd pick</td>
                <td class="selection">Jeffery, Alshon CHI WR</td>
                <td class="timestamp">3:13:15 p.m.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr classname="oddtablerow" class="oddtablerow" id="pick_01_03">
            ... Other rows here ...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1aawd1vL/59/

Answer (score 1):

The `.moohighlight` is not the `last-child`. So give `:last-of-type` instead:

```
.moohighlight:first-child td {background:red;}
tr:last-of-type td {background:green;}
```

Or:

```
.moohighlight:first-child td {background:red;}
tr:last-child td {background:green;}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1aawd1vL/17/**

But please note that the `last-of-type` selector can select only elements, not classes. It has not been implemented yet.

Comment: i can do the last tr , but i want the last instance of moohighlight

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks for noting... I have corrected it.

Comment: `:last-of-type` only works for an element tag. There is no `:last-of-class` pseudo-class for CSS yet.

Comment: ok thx , so i assume no way of doing what i need to do here , i need to get last .moohighlight and first .moohighlight , i can not use nth selectors as the data is dynamically added and i have no idea how many of those will reside in each table

Comment: @MShack If you want a selector that goes "I want the last-occurring element with the class `.moohighlight`", you will have to use JS.

Comment: @MShack - You could, I suppose, use a `tbody` for the `moohighlight` elements, and another for the rest, if they're all together. https://jsfiddle.net/1aawd1vL/59/

Comment: Jared , if i used tbody could i style 1st and last ?

Comment: @MShack - See the fiddle I added to the comment. But yes, the `last-child` has to be the last child of the *parent* element, not of the selector.

Comment: bingo , that is what i needed , ty Jared , if you wish to post this i can mark as answered. very nice work around !